# does anyone know what this show/cartoon is called?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, martial-arts

It's about two boys and one girl, they're all martial artists. When I watched it as kid it always played on Megamax. All I can remember is that the girl had black hair and one of the boys had hair accessories like Japanese culture.

There's one specific episode I remember and it's about how said boy I mentioned earlier tries to be as good as his idol but later finds out his idol is his dad. I do not remember more but it's been stuck in my head for weeks and I can't remember what show it was.

I grew up in Romania and watched it there so I am not aware if the show was only published in that country but I doubt it.

The antagonist lived with a giant glass on his head and his partner was not human (some sort of anthromorphic wolf or big food if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, in what sort of time period and location was the story set?

Comment: If you want to add any extra info here please [edit] it into your question rather than adding it as a comment. I’ve moved your comment into the answer for now as well as some other general cleaning up.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: By a "giant glass on his head", do you mean like w bowl helmet? Or a drinking glass perched on top?

Comment: Outside chance maybe, but the main characters weren't actually chickens were they?

Comment: I don't know if this is how I reply but yes there was an episode where they were chickens

Comment: @Renbee - You replied the correct way (by leaving a comment). Please respond to the other questions in the comments, like the one asking which year you watched this show in. It will very hard to identify this show if you don't answer any of these questions.